# MySQL: Column is empty in an insert log

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure in mysql:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createCompany ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE company varchar(5000) DEFAULT "";

    DEClARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT company FROM companies; 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1

    OPEN cur;

    getCompany: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO company;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getCompany;
        END IF;

        call LOG(company);
    END LOOP getCompany;
    CLOSE cur;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

LOG procedure is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `LOG`(IN message varchar(5000))
BEGIN
    insert into tmplog (log) values (message);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have a temporal table called tmplog with two fields: date and log (varchar(5000))

When I call createCompany I get the next result:

[image]

the log column is empty... what is wrong?

Comment: Try to rename your local variable, so it does not match the name of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having variables with the same name as columns is very dangerous.  Try this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_company varchar(5000) DEFAULT "";

    DEClARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT c.company FROM companies c; 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1

    OPEN cur;

    getCompany: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO v_company;
        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getCompany;
        END IF;

        call LOG(v_company);
    END LOOP getCompany;
    CLOSE cur;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thats true, I set v_ in the variable and now it is working, thx

Comment: @David . . . You could also fix it using the qualified column name (`c.company`).  There is a reason for best practices -- qualify column names and distinguish parameters from column names.